# How to save the input of Edittext to be used as global variable in basic for android program?

Tags: android, android-edittext, basic4android

I want to save the user's input in Edittext as a global variable so it can be used in other activities. I am using basic4android program.
Thanks,

I used this code

First Activity

Sub Process_Globals
    'These global variables will be declared once when the application starts.
    'These variables can be accessed from all modules.

```
X = EditText1.text
```

End Sub

Sub Globals
    'These global variables will be redeclared each time the activity is created.
    'These variables can only be accessed from this module.

```
**Private Button1 As Button
Private EditText1 As EditText
Public X As Double**

**Private Label1 As Label**
```

End Sub

Sub Activity_Create(FirstTime As Boolean)
    'Do not forget to load the layout file created with the visual designer. For example:
    'Activity.LoadLayout("Layout1")
Activity.LoadLayout("enter")

StartActivity("dessert")

End Sub

second acitivity

Sub Globals
    'These global variables will be redeclared each time the activity is created.
    'These variables can only be accessed from this module.

```
Private Label1 As Label
Private RadioButton1 As RadioButton
```

End Sub

Sub Activity_Create(FirstTime As Boolean)
    'Do not forget to load the layout file created with the visual designer. For example:
    'Activity.LoadLayout("Layout1")
    Activity.LoadLayout("dessert")

End Sub

Sub Activity_Resume

End Sub

Sub Activity_Pause (UserClosed As Boolean)

End Sub

Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChange(Checked As Boolean)

**Label1.text= X**

**I want to show the value of variable X in the label
End Sub**

**but it says the variable X is not declared and I already declared it in the first acitivity** **How to fix it ?**

Comment: Extend Application class and store your value there.

Answer (score 0):

Its not an answer. Its an idea. Use Shared Preference or sqlite db to store a value. And you can call and get it from other activities.